# Changing vowels to numbers in Bash prompt PS1

Tags: bash, ps1

I am trying to change my user prompt bash so that instead of showing up the vowels, it shows the number corresponding to that vowel. So, `a -> 1, e -> 2, i -> 3, o -> 4, u -> 5.`

So far what I achieved is all the vowels with the same number as you can see below. However I don't know how to do the aforementioned.

```
PS1='${USER//[io]/4}@ \D{%d-%m-%Y} - \w$ '
```

- Current name output: L4l4p4p (Lolipop)
- Expected name output: L4l5p4p

Can anyone help?

Thank you

Comment: A hint: You can include 1 or more bash functions to `PS1` to allow any modifications. Example: `PS1='... $(myfunction param) ...'`

Comment: As addition: do something like: `PS1='... $(tr aeiou 12345 <<<"INPUT" ) ...'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bash and parameter expansion:

```
PS1='$(USER="${USER//a/1}"; USER="${USER//e/2}"; USER="${USER//i/3}"; USER="${USER//o/4}"; echo "${USER//u/5}")@ \D{%d-%m-%Y} - \w$ '
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use sed.

```
PS1='$(<<<"$USER" sed "s/a/1/g;s/e/2/g;s/i/3/g;s/o/4/g;s/u/5/g") '
```

Comment: or `sed 'y/aeiou/12345/'`